# checkbox filtering on table with objects

Tags: mysql, angularjs, checkbox, filter, smart-table

I'm using AngularJS with smart-table module and I display a table with it.

The informations in rows are catched by "POST" request with MySQL.

These informations are stacked in a $scope.data_server declared in the app controller :

```
app.controller('SearchbddCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
   get_data();
function get_data() {
    var name = $scope.name;
    $http.post('/searchbdd', {name: name}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.data_server = data;
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        alert("Connection Error");
     });
    }
});
```

In front-end I display them like this :

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in displayCollection" st-select-row="data" st-select-mode="single">
<td>{{ data.login}}</td>
<td>{{ data.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

**What I want to do :**
 Filter these rows with multiple checkbox. I need 10 checkboxes.

I don't really know how to do it.. Does anyone has any infos or code example ??

**Example** :
For example, I have fruits (banana, apple and oranges) displayed in the table. I want to display in the table only bananas instead of bananas, apples and oranges.. Or if I want to display apples and oranges only. I check "oranges" and "apples" and it displays the rows which contains these types of fruits.

Update :

This is what I want to do : https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/issues/387

Comment: what do you mean with "filter these rows with multiple checkboxes" ? it's really ambiguous. can you better describe the functionality ?

Comment: For example, I have fruits. I want to display in the table only bananas instead of bananas, apples and oranges.. Or if I want to display apples and oranges only. I check "oranges" and "apples" and it displays the rows which contains these types of fruits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-repeat filter to do this.

For Sample if you have a column type in each row of your collection you can do something like the following :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="$scope.filter.type" value="banana"/>

<tr ng-repeat="data in displayCollection | filter:$scope.filter" st-select-row="data" st-select-mode="single">
<td>{{ data.login}}</td>
<td>{{ data.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, could you tell me what is "filter.type" ?
I mean when i use it, it hides every rows in the table.

Comment: What I want to do, it something like that : https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table/issues/387

Comment: ok i understand. in fact in my sample the object filter is a custom object without column by default. you can add each column of your object to filter on it. in my sample if you have a column type in your object you will be able to filter on the type banana by following my sample. if you have another column gender or category it will be something near $scope.filter.gender

Comment: Okay, In my case, I'm trying to display rows by filtering with a "status" which is not displayed in a column of the table but I get this status in $scope.data_server